# Prolog: predicate to check if elements of a list are present in a pre-defined list

Tags: prolog

I have a **fact** defined as:

```
list([1,2,3,4,5]).
```

Now, I want to write a predicate **pred(X)** which succeeds if all elements of X are present in the list. For example, pred([1,3,4,2]) should succeed, while pred([2,6,8]) should not.

**I tried the following:**

```
pred([],[]).
pred([H|T]) :- list(X), member(H,X), pred(T).
```

But, it always gives *false*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a recursive clause but not a base clause. Thus, when you finish traversing the list, the last call is `pred([])`, which will fail as it doesn't unify with the head of you single clause for the predicate.

Comment: I forget to write the base clause, but now I have edited my question. Unfortunately, even now it is not working.

Comment: @TanaySoni It is `pred([])` and not `pred([], [])`.

Comment: You need a `pred([])` base clause but you wrote instead `pred([],[])`.